# how to pass by reference a class var to a global var in PHP?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

please tell me theres a way around this...

```
$my_var = 'hello';

class Test{

    private $my_var;
    private $my_internal_var = 'if you see this it works!';

    function __construct(){
        global $my_var;

        $this->my_var = &$my_var;
    }

    function get_my_var(){
        return $this->my_var;
    }

    function set_my_var($value){
        $this->my_var = $value;
    }

    function set_my_var_to_internal_reference(){
        //this line should make $my_var in root, $my_var in this object, and $my_var in
        //all external functions point to $my_internal_var.
        $this->my_var = &$this->my_internal_var;
    }
}


function get_my_var(){
    global $my_var;

    return $my_var;
}

function set_my_var($value){
    global $my_var;

    $my_var = $value;
}


$my_obj = new Test();

echo '<h2>set default starting value</h2>';
echo 'obj : '.$my_obj->get_my_var().'<br>'; //echoes 'hello' - this is ok
echo 'func: '.get_my_var().'<br>'; //echoes 'hello' - this is ok
echo 'root: '.$my_var.'<br>'; //echoes 'hello' - this is ok

set_my_var('hello world!');

echo '<h2>set to value by function</h2>';
echo 'obj : '.$my_obj->get_my_var().'<br>'; //echoes 'hello world!' - this is ok
echo 'func: '.get_my_var().'<br>'; //echoes 'hello world!' - this is ok
echo 'root: '.$my_var.'<br>'; //echoes 'hello world!' - this is ok

$my_obj->set_my_var('hello world again!');

echo '<h2>set to value by object method</h2>';
echo 'obj : '.$my_obj->get_my_var().'<br>'; //echoes 'hello world again!' - this is ok
echo 'func: '.get_my_var().'<br>'; //echoes 'hello world again!' - this is ok
echo 'root: '.$my_var.'<br>'; //echoes 'hello world again!' - this is ok

$my_obj->set_my_var_to_internal_reference();

echo '<h2>set to object internal reference</h2>';
echo 'obj : '.$my_obj->get_my_var().'<br>'; //echoes '      ' - this is NOT ok. should be 'if you see this it works!'
echo 'func: '.get_my_var().'<br>'; //echoes 'hello world again!' - this is NOT ok. should be 'if you see this it works!'
echo 'root: '.$my_var.'<br>'; //echoes 'hello world again!' - this is NOT ok. should be 'if you see this it works!'
```

Thanks!!

Comment: thanks erenon,the thing is I already tried the registry pattern, singletons,etc and this is what has given me most successful results. What I need is a way to make a change or read a var that is available everywhere and this follow through to a var inside an object. So my idea was to make the "everywhere" var be a reference to the object's internal var. But this is not happening. I know the references I have setup are working correctly because it works in almost every case, except when I try to make a reference var=to another reference.
$everywhere_var -references-> $obj_var1 -refs-> $obj_var2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT ok as is. You should use a wrapper object in OO enviorment, and don't use global vars, they are sucks. **Example**:

```
class My_Registry{
    private $registry = array();

    public function set_var($key, $var){
        $this->registry[$key] = $var;
        return $this;
    }

    public function get_var($key){
       if(isset($this->registry[$key]){
           return $this->registry[$key]
       }else{
           return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Or something like this, you can add error handling, privileges, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ampersand (`&`) in front of a variable in the function arguments definition to force it to pass by reference. Likewise, use an ampersand in front of the value which you are assigning to a variable to force an assignment by reference instead of by value.

```
function foo(&$var)
{
    // $var is passed by reference to this function
}

$var = $var2;  // assigns $var the value of $var2
$var = &$var2; // assigns $var the same reference as $var2
```

For more detail, see the PHP manual section [References Explained](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Answer (score 0):

`$my_internal_var` is a global and not a class variable, so this line can't possibly work:

```
$this->my_var = &$this->my_internal_var;
```

`$this->my_internal_var` doesn't exist.

Why aren't you using the same logic you're already using in some of your other functions/methods? For setting one global variable to a reference of another, though, you need to use the `$GLOBALS` array:

```
function set_my_var_to_internal_reference(){
    global $my_internal_var;

    $this->my_var = &$my_internal_var;
    $GLOBALS['my_var'] = &$my_internal_var;
}
```

Have a look at the [PHP manual page about variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Oh, and as much as this may make it work for you now, I'm with [erenon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370308/how-to-pass-by-reference-a-class-var-to-a-global-var-in-php/1370342#1370342) in that you should avoid using globals...

- [Global variables: When ARE they acceptable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357187/global-variables-when-are-they-acceptable)
- [Global Variables Are Bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)
- Wikipedia: [Global variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable)